# Java AI Not Following the Player

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

So, I am taking a Java tutorial from RealTutsGML, and I am on the last part of episode seven. I have a problem though - the enemy AI does not work as it should - it does not follow the player all the time, and when it does, it's jittery and only within short range. Also the enemy only moves towards the bottom right.

Here is all of my code: (The needed parts)

```
package com.project.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2379768900378456337L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    private Random r;
    private Handler handler;
    private HUD hud;
    private Spawn spawner;

    public Game(){
        handler = new Handler();
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));

        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Dodge BETA", this);

        hud = new HUD();
        spawner = new Spawn(handler, hud);
        r = new Random();

        handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH/2-32, HEIGHT/2-32, ID.Player, handler));
        handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH - 32), r.nextInt(HEIGHT - 32), ID.BasicEnemy, handler));
    }


    public synchronized void start(){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        try{
            thread.join();
            running = false;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick(){
        handler.tick();
        hud.tick();
        spawner.tick();
    }

    private void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        handler.render(g);

        hud.render(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static float clamp(float var, float min, float max){
        if(var >= max)
            return var = max;
        else if(var <= min)
            return var = min;
        else
            return var;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Game();
    }

}
```

GameObject is the master class for the enemies and player. It assists using a lot of premade methods to make stuff easier and cleaner.

```
package com.project.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class GameObject {

    protected float x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected float velX, velY;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);
    public abstract Rectangle getBounds();

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    public float getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public float getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public void setId(ID id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ID getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setVelX(int velX){
        this.velX = velX;
    }
    public void setVelY(int velY){
        this.velY = velY;
    }
    public float getVelX(){
        return velX;
    }
    public float getVelY(){
        return velY;
    }

}
```

The Handler Class
This class helps add objects into the game and remove them, as well as updating them and rendering the object.

```
package com.project.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Handler {

    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.remove(object);
    }

}
```

THE SMARTENEMY AI CLASS is supposed to create the smart enemy that follows the player around - but as I previously explained, its really buggy.

```
package com.project.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class SmartEnemy extends GameObject{

    private Handler handler;
    private GameObject player;

    public SmartEnemy(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            if(handler.object.get(i).getId() == ID.Player) player = handler.object.get(i);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);
    }

    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        float diffX = x - player.getX() - 8;
        float diffY = y - player.getY() - 8;
        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((x - player.getX())*(x - player.getX()) + (y-player.getY())*(y-player.getY()));

        velX = (int) ((-1.0/distance) * diffX);
        velY = (int) ((-1.0/distance) * diffY);

        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 50) velY *= -1;
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 20) velX *= -1;

        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.green, 16, 16, 0.03f, handler));
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 16, 16);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and include the relevant code, or better yet an [MCVE]. We can't figure out what's wrong with your code unless you actually show us.

Comment: Way too much code. This is not a [mcve]. You are asking too much of people to wade through all this.

Comment: [use a debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gAjIQc4bPU)

Comment: OK I tidied up my code and added descriptions. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind:
If it only moves right and down it indicates that your deltas are always positive (velX, velY). It's not apparent from the code i SMARTENEMY why this happens.

Secondly, as `distance` grows velocity will drop. This is probably why it only works on short distances.

Thirdly, if you flip the arguments for your diff calculation (player.x - x) you can drop the -1f on the velocity calculation.
I don't understand why the velocity should be dependent on the distance, though.